# using terraform to obtain a list of ipv4 addresses from a html file

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to obtain a list of IPV4 addresses from a webfile written in JSON, using terraform.

Can anyone offer any solutions to extract simply the IPV4 addresses (the file has a mixture of IPV4 and IPV6)

So far i've been able to store the file contents in a variable, but can't seem to figure out a function to obtain IPV4s.

```
data "http" "atlassian_ip_ranges" {
  url = "https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com"
}

locals {
  atlassian_ipv4_cidrs = "${flatten(keys(jsondecode(data.http.atlassian_ip_ranges.body)))}"
}
```

was only able to extract the whole file

Comment: What is an example of `data.http.atlassian_ip_ranges.body`?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the items returned in the JSON response with a regex filter.

The example below would create a new local ipv4_cidrs list with filtered IPv4 CIDRs.

This is using Terraform [for](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) to iterate each item in the returned items array, and a [can](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/can) to determine if it is IPv4 using a [regex](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regex); if so, add it to the list.

```
data "http" "atlassian_ip_ranges" {
  url = "https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com"
}

locals {
  atlassian_cidrs = "${(jsondecode(data.http.atlassian_ip_ranges.body))}"
  ipv4_cidrs      = [for item in local.atlassian_cidrs.items : item.cidr if can(regex("^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\/[0-9]{1,2}$", item.cidr))]
}
```